# Could Winter Bash Be Extended to Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2012

Could the Winter Bash be added to the Area 51 site in the future or is too different from other Stack sites. I know you can up/down vote, posts answers and comments like the other sites.

Answer (score 11):

I remember considering this when I was doing the master opt in/out tracker and debating this.

There's really two big reasons I left Area 51 out of this:

1. There really isn't a *community* of people who *just* hang out on Area 51. I love Area 51 as much as anyone, but as a user I spend my time on the sites that are more directly relevant to my interests -- SciFi, Movies, DIY, etc.
2. This is actually the more important reason: Area 51 is sometimes the first site non-network people see of ours. It's where they send out links to other pros and experts in their fields to join and recruit support for their proposals. I love hats -- I *really* love hats! -- but they aren't going to project the right tone for that site and its purpose. It's similar to why we don't have hats on the rep league pages.

I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this -- it's a great request, but I thought long and hard about whether or not we should have hats there.

Comment: Ok. I love hats too and was just thinking about the unique hats that could be made to interact with commitments and how it could even bring the user base of the others sites to actually look at Area51 and get involved. Good points, just wish I could get a cool Alien Hat for being over there haha. Thanks.

Comment: Adding an alien hat is a really good idea! I'll put it on my List of Things For 2.0! :)

Comment: We might also have had some technical challenges/additional work, since A51 is a separate codebase.